# What's the difference between min-width and max-width?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning @media query and I've seen some codes with min-width and some codes with max-width.

What is the difference?

Which is better for the usage in @media query.

Thanks

I've tried both (min-width and max-width) but I was unable to see a difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Which is better" is opinion based. I would say in general you style mobile first, so `min-width` would be used for higher screen width, it's probably used more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want the background-color of the body tag to be black for screen sizes smaller than 800px, you need to use max-width, which means only apply these styles if the width of the screen is not bigger than 800px(the maximum width is 800px).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

but if you want a style to be applied for screen sizes which are at least 800px wide(bigger than 800px), you should use min-width instead.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)  {...}**
What this query really means, is “If [device width] is greater than or equal to 600px, then do {…}”

**@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {...}**
What this query really means, is “If [device width] is lesser than or equal to 600px, then do {…}”

**@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 400px)  {...}**

The query above will trigger only for screens that are 600-400px wide. This can be used to target specific devices with known widths.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explenation Bahubali.